# Eclipse 3.5 ugrade

Tags: eclipse

I got a notification to upgrade eclipse yesterday so I did it.  When I started it up again today it ask for another upgrade.  So I looked through the list and most of the dates were pretty old.  I did the upgrade and the shut down and started eclipse and it asked for the same upgrades again.  Should I just do a clean install?  Why is this happening.

Comment: move to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run eclipse with the `-clean` flag.
To do that, create a shortcut to eclipse and add `-clean` at the end at the call.

Anyway, a fresh install will be great!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have run the new installation of Eclipse after the upgrade?
What does the **Help | About Eclipse** say?